# Web2py error "pydal.objects.Expression object" when doing table.field.max()

Tags: web2py

I believe i am following the code here: http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer?search=insert#sum-avg-min-max-and-len

The insert works fine. 
The max() lines gives an error: pydal.objects.Expression object at 0x0000024D079AF748

What am I doing wrong?

The model:

```
db = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite')

db.define_table(
    'CardMasters',
    Field('Name'),
    Field('Categories'),
    Field('Description'),
    singular="Card Master", plural="Card Masters",
    format = '%(Name)s (%(Description)s)')
```

The controller:

```
def test():
    id = db.CardMasters.insert(Name='please work')
    maxName = db.CardMasters.Name.max()
    maxid = db.CardMasters.id.max()

    return locals()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not getting an error. Rather, you are returning two PyDAL `Expression` objects (the `.max()` method of a DAL `Field` object returns an `Expression` object). If you are then trying to include those objects in your view, they will be converted to strings, and when you convert an arbitrary Python object to a string, you get a default string representation of the object like `<pydal.objects.Expression object at 0x0000024D079AF748>`.

Presumably what you meant to do was to query the database to find the max name (which would be the last one alphabetically) and the max `id`. To get those values, you can do something like this:

```
    maxName = db.CardMasters.Name.max()
    maxid = db.CardMasters.id.max()
    row = db(db.CardMasters).select(maxName, maxid).first()
    return dict(id=id, maxName=row[maxName], maxid=row[maxid])
```

In the view, you can then do:

```
{{=maxName}}
{{=maxid}}
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony! I wasn't sure i would get an answer.

Comment: Worked perfectly of course. I read the docs but didn't notice how to retrieve the value even though it was right in front of me!

For newbies like me, the 'db.CardMasters' in the third line is not needed. That confused me a little.  

This works fine: row = db().select(maxName, maxid).first()  

I wasn't sure i would get an answer. Definitely didn't think i would get one from the master. I don't have any reputation on stackoverflow but i still vote up your answers. I have read sooo many of them over the last month you feel like a good friend :-) Thanks, for the last 10yrs!!!